# Embed content above Salesforce tabs

Tags: visualforce, javascript, home-page-component, static-resources

I was just checking out this app in the AppExchange, and I want to implement something similar in my own company: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005ueMvEAI

Any idea what they're doing to embed their "ticker" content above the tab pane for all SFDC pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Home Page component that is embedded on the side of most pages.

You can run custom code from the sidebar using the general following steps:

First, click on Setup > Customize > Home > Home Page Components > New (HTML, narrow). Next, toggle the HTML view mode (the checkbox). Then, enter in some sort of JavaScript. For example, you might do something like this:

```
<script src="/resource/myLibrary" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Click "Save" without unchecking the HTML view option.

Next, Setup > Customize > Home Page > Home Page Layouts, create or modify an existing layout to use the new feature. Also, assign the layout to profiles that should be able to see the feature.

Finally, Setup > Customize > User Interface, make sure you are showing custom home page components on all pages.

In this example, the source was uploaded to a Static Resource called myLibrary, so you'd want to do the same if you chose to use a Static Resource. You could also host it as a Document, an Attachment, or on some external server (but I would strongly recommend it be served from an HTTPS link).

The script itself could be whatever you choose to do. In their case, they perform a document query to find the tab bar, then insert their own custom element immediately above/before it. From there, it's all JavaScript, querying new data, that sort of stuff.

I myself had implemented Multilingual Field Level Help some years (May 2007) before salesforce.com released their own version; it used the same logical concept of embedding code in the sidebar. Unfortunately, it's an S-Control and uses obsolete browser technology, so it doesn't function, but it was a decent proof of concept.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this and, with a little DOM manipulation, got a good working version!

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get this partially working - my script tag was embedded nicely in the home page (using the default layout). However, I could not find the "show custom home page components on all pages" option you referred to under Setup > Customize > User interface, and so the script tag is not embedded on any other tab. Is there some additional setting to enable that?

Comment: To answer myself - I found the setting is for showing custom Sidebar components on all pages, so my tag is now embedded on all pages that have the sidebar in them

Comment: I just tried this and it is not working, is there any other workaround?